# Java Cannot include jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, netbeans, directive

i am trying to directive include a .jsp page in Java but the link is not recognized by Netbeans 8.2 and is showed as plain text.

```
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/templates/header.html" %>
```

How can i solve this?

Comment: Could you show the JSP code that isn't working for you?

Comment: I have added the JSP code

Answer (score 0):

You cannot read from the `WEB-INF` directory. Have a look at [this document](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnadx.html) to see how a WAR file should be organised.